# Things to do after cloning smaller ssd to larger ssd in ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, ssd, dd, clone

I cloned a 500GB ssd to a 1050GB ssd but I was having many issues later. I only cloned the partitions I need then later resized them. The swap partition is the only one that I didn't clone because I already have 16GB of ram.

System infos: ubu 16.04, Moved from Samsung Evo 500GB to Crucial MX300 1050GB. Dual booting between win 10 and ubu 16.04 in both. All partitions cloned except swap.

Problems that arose after cloning:

- No internet access in browsers although connected to wifi: #fixed by editing resolve file
- Slow boot time for ubuntu: no found fix yet, slower than HDD actually :( but windows partition is fine  and boots very fast.
- Boot screen disappeared, (no plymounth or splash screen) forgot how to get this back.
- I'm just experimenting with it for now, if I find any more issues, I'll post but I just hope someone can help with the issues I was not able to fix.

Comment: Probably you need to edit fstab (and issue swapoff).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the slow boot issue! Now if only I can get my boot screen back.

Comment: This is a Q&A, one question for one answer is how it should work. If you intend to discuss several topics at once a forum is better.

Comment: So everything is fixed except [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth)?

Comment: Yes, everything is fixed except Plymouth.

Comment: Was it any help when you clicked on [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth)?

Comment: I re-installed Plymouth and some other Plymouth related stuff using synaptic. Seems to have everything fixed by now. Thanks for your helps.